# awk match pattern from file

Tags: awk

I have very large data sets in which I need to find specific patterns located in a specific column index and need the entire line output. I've gotten [successfully] as far as a single cmd line pattern match:

`awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$1=="100002"{print $1,$22,$11,$12,$13,$28,$25,$27}' searchfile > outfile`

`100022` - being the search pattern, is a an exact match and located in column 1
`searchfile` - is the data file with 3.8 million lines and 60 columns all `|` delimited

Now I want to modify this search by specifying an input `patternfile`, because I have a little over 800 patterns that need to be matched and outputted. I've done my best to search the site and did find the use of the `-f` flag however I don't know how to integrate that with my search criteria per above. I need to be able to specify: exact match, specific column index search, specify specific columns to output, and specific in/out delimiter.

sample data set (note this has been modified to protect data owner):
`100001|0|60|100001|AAR Corp| | |Industrial|Aerospace/Defense|Aerospace/Defense-Equip|US|US|US|IL|DE|;2;6;1;1;1100 North Wood Dale Road;1; ;1;Wood Dale;1;IL;1;60191;1;United States;|
15460796|0|60|15460796|PayPal Data Services Inc|348546|eBay Inc|Consumer, Non-cyclical|Commercial Services|Inactive/Unknown|US|US|US|CA|DE|;2;6;1;1;2211 North 1st Street;1; ;1;San Jose;1;CA;1;95125;1;United States;|
100003|0|60|100003|Abex Inc|170435|Mafco Consolidated Group Inc|Industrial|Aerospace/Defense|Aerospace/Defense-Equip|US|US|US|NH|DE|;2;6;1;1;Liberty Lane;1; ;1;Hampton;1;NH;1;03842;1;United States;|
100004|0|60|100004|Abitibi-Consolidated Inc|23165941|Resolute Forest Products Inc|Basic Materials|Forest Products&Paper|Paper&Related Products|CA|CA|CA|QC|QC|;2;6;1;1;1155 Metcalfe Street;1;Suite 800;1;Montreal;1;QC;1;M5J 2P5;1;Canada;|
100005|0|60|100005|Acme Electric Corp|100763|Hubbell Inc|Industrial|Electrical Compo&Equip|Power Conv/Supply Equip|US|US|US|NC|NY|;2;6;1;1;400 Quaker Road;1; ;1;East Aurora;1;NY;1;14052;1;United States;|
100006|0|60|100006|ACME-Cleveland Corp|100430|Danaher Corp|Industrial|Hand/Machine Tools|Mach Tools&Rel Products|US|US|US|OH|OH|;2;6;1;1;30100 Chagrin Boulevard;1;Suite 100;1;Pepper Pike;1;OH;1;44124-5705;1;United States;|
100007|0|60|100007|Acuson Corp|196005|Siemens Corp|Consumer, Non-cyclical|Healthcare-Products|Ultra Sound Imaging Sys|US|US|US|CA|DE|;2;6;1;1;1220 Charleston Road;1; ;1;Mountain View;1;CA;1;94039;1;United States;|
100009|0|60|100009|ADT Ltd|101520|Tyco International Plc|Consumer, Non-cyclical|Commercial Services|Protection-Safety|BM|BM|BM| | |;2;6;1;1;Cedar House;1;41 Cedar Avenue;1;Hamilton;1; ;1;HM 12;1;Bermuda;|
100010|0|60|100010|Advanced Micro Devices Inc| | |Technology|Semiconductors|Electronic Compo-Semicon|US|US|US|CA|DE|;2;6;1;1;One AMD Place;1;PO Box 3453;1;Sunnyvale;1;CA;1;94088-3453;1;United States;|`

input pattern search:
`100006
100052`

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Its proprietary data, I can describe the data sets would I would not be in a position to share the specifics?

Comment: No-one expects you to post proprietary data. Just make stuff up that's formatted like your real data. And, of course, just use 4 or 5 columns, not 27+!

Comment: Thank you, I posted based on your recommendations, the actual data set is 60 columns and 3.8 million lines. The search patterns can occur in multiple columns and as sub-text which is why I need to specify the specific search column and exact match

Comment: Seems like you went with many more than 4 or 5 columns of input. The more irrelevant data you throw into your question the harder it becomes to read/understand and so the fewer people will bother to try and so the less help you'll get. Also you forgot to post the expected output given your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize all the variables from the script

```
$ awk -v sep='|' -v matchindex='1' -v matchvalue='100002' -v columns='1,22,11,12,13,28,25,27'
                             'BEGIN{FS=OFS=sep; n=split(columns,c,",")}
            $matchindex==matchvalue{for(i=1;i<n;i++) 
                                     printf "%s",$c[i] OFS; printf "%s\n", $c[n]}'
```

and perhaps write another script to generate the first line from a config file.

Comment: I'm confused by your suggestion. In my original post `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$1=="100002"{print $1,$22,$11,$12,$13,$28,$25,$27}' searchfile > outfile` works perfectly fine; the only problem with this is that I have 800+ search patterns, so naturally I would like to specific an input pattern file instead of having to repeat the cmd 800+ times.

Comment: based on your " I need to be able to specific: exact match, specific column index search, specify specific columns to output, and specific in/out delimiter."  I simply externalized all variables.  Just change the input arguments and keep the script the same.